# CSS: Transparent 'section' in solid colour navigation bar

Tags: html, css, css-float

having some CSS difficulties and hoping someone can help me out.

I am trying to get the navbar to expand out on both sides of the page (filled with a solid color), but have a transparent space where I can squeeze in my logo (as seen in the image below).

My page background is an image, so I can't just fill the {Logo} cell, with a bg colour - If it helps at all, I am also using Twitter Bootstrap.

Please can someone help me out with this. Been stuck for a a while now. :S

[image: Layout Example]

Comment: Simplest approach is to build your nav bar as image with the transparent bit, make it wide enough (2000px) then put it as background on the nav bar and position it to fit your needs and align the transparent section with your logo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this (no image needed, just pure css) :

http://jsfiddle.net/Jh4ya/6/

You have the right side of your navbar positioned as absolute :

```
#right {
    left: 250px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    background: #469;
    top: 0px;
}
```

I think it is one of the most cleanest way to do it. Hope it helps

EDIT :

It may faces some widths issues. As a workarround, you could use `display: table-cell;` and `display: table;` properties. See this fork : http://jsfiddle.net/qxVce/

Answer (score 0):

I was referring to something like this in my comment http://jsfiddle.net/slash197/Eh2xL/1/ This is just a proof of concept, you need to change the values and sizes.

HTML

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
.bg {
    background: url("http://slashwebdesign.net/green-nature-wallpaper2.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0px;
}
.nav {
    background: url("http://slashwebdesign.net/nav.png") no-repeat center top;
    height: 35px;
}
.logo {
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```